# How to perform an FFT as a layer of a in a keras model with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to perform an FFT as a layer in a keras model via tensorflow.
I have tried a reduced version of the network as follows, but you can see that the FFT layer is removing the imaginary portion of the input and not giving the expected output. Can anyone explain what is going on here?  Is there a better approach?  Note: I am using tensorflow 1.12.0. You can see how it differs from the numpy approach below:

```
import tensorflow 
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tf.__version__
'1.12.0'
s = np.sin(np.linspace(0,4*3.14,64))
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,1))
x = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda v: tf.spectral.fft(tf.cast(v,tf.complex64)))(inputs)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=x)
y = model.predict(s.reshape(1,64,1))
y


array([[[ 0.        +0.j],
    [ 0.19804703+0.j],
    [ 0.3882484 +0.j],
    [ 0.5630694 +0.j],
    [ 0.71558434+0.j],
    [ 0.8397515 +0.j],
    [ 0.9306519 +0.j],
    [ 0.9846846 +0.j],
    [ 0.999709  +0.j],
    [ 0.97513   +0.j],
    [ 0.91192126+0.j],
    [ 0.81258684+0.j],
    [ 0.68106174+0.j],
    [ 0.5225565 +0.j],
    [ 0.3433501 +0.j],
    [ 0.15054196+0.j],
    [-0.0482299 +0.j],
    [-0.24509114+0.j],
    [-0.4322431 +0.j],
    [-0.6022718 +0.j],
    [-0.74844146+0.j],
    [-0.8649617 +0.j],
    [-0.94721645+0.j],
    [-0.99194735+0.j],
    [-0.9973822 +0.j],
    [-0.96330583+0.j],
    [-0.89106816+0.j],
    [-0.78353083+0.j],
    [-0.644954  +0.j],
    [-0.4808273 +0.j],
    [-0.29765266+0.j],
    [-0.10268652+0.j],
    [ 0.09634754+0.j],
    [ 0.2915648 +0.j],
    [ 0.47523174+0.j],
    [ 0.6400724 +0.j],
    [ 0.7795566 +0.j],
    [ 0.8881587 +0.j],
    [ 0.9615764 +0.j],
    [ 0.99690133+0.j],
    [ 0.992734  +0.j],
    [ 0.9492396 +0.j],
    [ 0.8681411 +0.j],
    [ 0.7526513 +0.j],
    [ 0.6073451 +0.j],
    [ 0.43797904+0.j],
    [ 0.25126243+0.j],
    [ 0.05459208+0.j],
    [-0.14424095+0.j],
    [-0.33735985+0.j],
    [-0.5171143 +0.j],
    [-0.67638326+0.j],
    [-0.8088573 +0.j],
    [-0.9092885 +0.j],
    [-0.9736983 +0.j],
    [-0.9995351 +0.j],
    [-0.9857753 +0.j],
    [-0.9329641 +0.j],
    [-0.8431935 +0.j],
    [-0.7200199 +0.j],
    [-0.56832266+0.j],
    [-0.39411137+0.j],
    [-0.2042874 +0.j],
    [-0.00637057+0.j]]], dtype=complex64)

np.fft.rfft(s)
array([-0.00308384+0.00000000e+00j,  0.02672711-6.26977476e-01j,
    3.00558863-3.15625216e+01j, -0.1749646 +1.19722520e+00j,
   -0.12854614+6.51698290e-01j, -0.11460713+4.60018771e-01j,
   -0.10826083+3.58242071e-01j, -0.10477286+2.93644521e-01j,
   -0.10263141+2.48314149e-01j, -0.10121581+2.14376326e-01j,
   -0.1002289 +1.87784215e-01j, -0.09951263+1.66227088e-01j,
   -0.09897615+1.48281277e-01j, -0.09856407+1.33017648e-01j,
   -0.09824097+1.19801769e-01j, -0.0979833 +1.08184304e-01j,
   -0.0977749 +9.78372194e-02j, -0.0976044 +8.85148156e-02j,
   -0.09746356+8.00289334e-02j, -0.09734636+7.22326372e-02j,
   -0.09724825+6.50091522e-02j, -0.09716581+5.82641686e-02j,
   -0.0970964 +5.19203650e-02j, -0.09703796+4.59134283e-02j,
   -0.09698889+4.01891074e-02j, -0.09694793+3.47009899e-02j,
   -0.09691409+2.94087961e-02j, -0.0968866 +2.42770460e-02j,
   -0.09686484+1.92739961e-02j, -0.09684836+1.43707750e-02j,
   -0.09683682+9.54066251e-03j, -0.09682999+4.75847143e-03j,
   -0.09682773+0.00000000e+00j])
```

Note that the model summary is as follows:

Model: "model"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, None, 1)]         0

---

## lambda (Lambda)              (None, None, 1)           0

Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0

However, I have seen this on a more recent version of tensorflow (2.6.2) - exact same result.
There I used the following:

```
x = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda v: tf.signal.fft(tf.cast(v,tf.complex64)))(inputs)
```

Note: the "signal" attribute, instead of the "spectral".

Is the lambda layer going to allow for backpropagation of error to prior network layers?

I would really like to get this working on tensorflow 1.12.0, but could upgrade, if that is better/necessary to fix.

Any information that can be provided to help solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on TF v2.5.0, where `tf.spectral.fft` has been replaced with `tf.signal.fft`. According to [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/fft), this function

> Computes the 1-dimensional discrete Fourier transform **over the inner-most dimension** of input.

Since the last dimension of your inputs is `1`, the function does not compute FFT for the series, but for each individual number in the series. Seeing that FFT of a number is the number itself, your output will be exactly the same as your input.

You can fix this by the following two lines

```
inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
y = model.predict(s.reshape(1,64))
```

Comment: Thank you so very much.  This was indeed the problem and your suggestion fixed it for the tensorflow "spectral" package as well! Very much appreciated!